# basic project setup with multiple components

Tags: cmake

What is the best way to set up a project which has several independent components?

My project does not have a top-level CMakeLists file, it consists of multiple components. Some of them can be built independently, while some depend on other components.
For example, component A and B can be build and used by themselves (and may consist of several separate targets), while component C requires A and B to build.

Project layout:

```
    ├───component_A
    │       CMakeLists.txt
    │       main.cpp
    │
    ├───component_B
    │       CMakeLists.txt
    │       main.cpp
    │
    └───component_C
             CMakeLists.txt
             main.cpp
```

I can see 3 possibilities but none of them seem efficient or workable:

1. Use add_subdirectory(component_A CMAKE_BINARY_DIR/componentA).
2. ExternalProject_Add() seems too limited to handle extensive components
3. Treat every component as a package and use find_package
   to include  them. How would configuring, installing, etc work in
   this case?

Comment: "I can see 3 possibilities but none of them seem efficient or workable" - Actually, any of them could work. Just try.

Answer (score 0):

One straight-forward solution is to create a top-level CMake with some CMake [`options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html) to give you some control over what is included in your overall project. These options will populate and can be changed in the CMake GUI, but can also be controlled if running `cmake` from the command line. Here is what a simple top-level CMake file for your situation might look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(TopLevelProject)

# Define options to easily turn components ON or OFF.
option(ENABLE_COMPONENT_A "Option to include component A" ON)
option(ENABLE_COMPONENT_B "Option to include component B" OFF)
option(ENABLE_COMPONENT_C "Option to include component C" OFF)

# Determine which components are included and built by default in ALL_BUILD.
if(ENABLE_COMPONENT_C)
    # Need all three components in this case.
    add_subdirectory(component_A)
    add_subdirectory(component_B)
    add_subdirectory(component_C)
else()
    if(ENABLE_COMPONENT_A)
        add_subdirectory(component_A)
    endif()
    if(ENABLE_COMPONENT_B)
        add_subdirectory(component_B)
    endif()
endif()
```

In this example, only option A is `ON`, so only component A will be included in the generated buildsystem. Even if you include all the components, you can still choose which projects (or targets) to build individually after the buildsystem is generated.